# Increasing performance with octant search algorithm

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, search

I am working on an octant search to find the n-number(e.g. 8) of points (+) closest to my circular point (o) in each octant. This would mean that my points (+) are reduced to only 64 (8 per octant).

[image]

The first thing I did is to divide my region into octants with my point (o) as reference.

[image]

data = array containing (x, y, z) for all points (+)
gdata = array containing (x, y) for point (o)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from collections import defaultdict

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
nrow, cols = data.shape

file_path1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
gdata = pd.read_excel(file_path1)
gdata = np.array(gdata, dtype=np.float)

pwangle = np.zeros(nrow)

for j in range(nrow):
    delta_x = gdata[:,0]-data[:,0][j]
    delta_y = gdata[:,1]-data[:,1][j]
    if delta_x != 0:
        pwangle[j] = np.rad2deg(np.arctan(delta_y/delta_x))
    else:
        if delta_y > 0:
            pwangle[j] = 90
        elif delta_y < 0:
            pwangle[j] = 270
    if (delta_x < 0)&(delta_y > 0):
        pwangle[j] = 180 + pwangle[j]
    elif (delta_x < 0)&(delta_y < 0):
        pwangle[j] = 270 - pwangle[j]
    elif (delta_x > 0)&(delta_y < 0):
        pwangle[j] = 360 + pwangle[j]

vecangle = pwangle.ravel()
sortdata = defaultdict(list)
count = -1
get_anglesector = 45

N = 8
d = cdist(data[:,:2], gdata)
P = np.hstack((data, d)) 

for j in range(0, 360, get_anglesector):
    count += 1
    get_data = []
    for k, dummy_val in enumerate(vecangle):
        if j <= vecangle[k] < j + get_anglesector:
            get_data.append(P[k,::])
            sortdata[count] = np.array(get_data)
```

After data have been grouped into various octant, I then sort data in each octant to obtain the closest 8 data to the point (o).

```
for i, j in enumerate(sortdata):   
    octantsort = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(8):
        octantsort[i] = np.array(sortdata[i][sortdata[i][:,3].argsort()[:N]])
```

Is there an efficient and pythonic way of doing this do increase performance?

This works fine but when i have more than one 'o' point (e.g. 10000 points 'o') and I have run the above code for each point, it would be time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job gets a lot easier if you use [`arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) instead of `arctan`. Then vectorizing for speed we may get something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

delta = gdata - data[:,:2]
angles = np.arctan2(delta[:,1], delta[:,0])
bins = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 9)
bins[-1] = np.inf  # handle edge case
octantsort = []
for i in range(8):
    data_i = data[(bins[i] <= angles) & (angles < bins[i+1])]
    dist_order = np.argsort(cdist(data_i, gdata))
    octantsort.append(data_i[dist_order[:N]])
```

Comment: what if i after getting the element in the ´octantsort` I want to get the first 10 elements closest to the circular point (o) and which do not appear in ´octantsort`. and with this second case, bins =np.linspace(-np.pi + np.pi/8, np.pi + np.pi/8, 9). How can I effectively do it?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @user7138814, apart from making some slight changes, your code is faster

```
N=8  
delta = gdata - data[:,:2]
angles = np.arctan2(delta[:,1], delta[:,0])
bins = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 9)
bins[-1] = np.inf  # handle edge case
octantsort = []
for i in range(8):
    data_i = data[(bins[i] <= angles) & (angles < bins[i+1])]
    dist_order = np.argsort(cdist(data_i[:,:2], gdata), axis=0)
    [octantsort.append(data_i[dist_order[:N][j]]) for j in range(8)]
final = np.vstack(octantsort)
```

Time of execution of the previous code (code in the question):

```
 ---- 0.021449804306030273 seconds ------
```

Time of execution of the code in this post:

```
---- 0.0015172958374023438 seconds ------
```